# The type of 'i' below in main(). Why is it an int&?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I know the type of `i` below in `main()` is an `int&`. That's why it must be initialized.

```
int& f(){ static int i = 1; return i; }

int main()
{
    decltype(f()) i = f();
}
```

But using paragraph `5p5` in the Standard, I conclude that the expression `f()` has type `int` as the reference is dropped.

From `7.1.6.2p4`, how can one say that the expression `f()` is an lvalue, given that the reference was dropped from the function return?

Comment: Note how this is almost exactly the way the C++14 `decltype(auto)` feature works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reference is dropped when evaluating the type of the expression (as per § 5/5), but this does not change the fact that the function call expression `f()` is an *lvalue*. Per paragraph 5.2.2/10 of the C++11 Standard:

> A function call is an *lvalue* if the result type is an *lvalue* reference type or an *rvalue* reference to function
>   type, an *xvalue* if the result type is an *rvalue* reference to object type, and a *prvalue* otherwise.

In other words, the reference is not dropped from the return type of the function itself, only from the type of the evaluated function call expression (which is, therefore, `int`).

The fact that the function is returning an *lvalue* reference is what allows the type system to classify corresponding function call expressions as *lvalues* - which, in turn, allows `decltype` to add the *lvalue* reference to the type of the expression, thus yielding `int&`.